# Is the function $f(n)=\begin{cases} 0,& \text{If $CH$} \\ 1,& \text{If $\lnot CH$} \end{cases}$ $\mu$-recursive?

Tags: logic, computability

Using a Turing machine model of computation one can show that the function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, given by:

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
0,& \text{If $CH$} \\
1,& \text{If  $\lnot CH$}
\end{cases}$$

is computable (where $CH$ is the continuum hypothesis) .

I read that the set of $\mu$-recursive functions is equal to the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself that are computed by some Turing machine.

It seems very strange for me that the function $f$ I defined above is $\mu$-recursive. I would like someone to show me how one can use the bases functions (identity, projection,successor) along with composition, recursion, minimization to get $f$.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is constant, constant functions are recursive. Of course, depending on whether you accept or reject the continuity hypothesis, the function is either constantly equal to $1$ or to $0$, but either way, it is constant.

Comment: opps! ok, thank you